# Any suggestions on a method to change an SQLite date format for all database items at once, either in python or SQL?

Tags: python, sqlite

Each item in this current database uses the date format mm/dd/yyyy - However, to use any of the date sqlite functions I believe it has to be something like YYYY-MM-DD.  There are a few variations but essentially I need year first and "-" instead of "/".  I am trying to think of a way to change all of them at once in a loop, probably in python, but am stuck because the current format is not recognized as a date at all, even though the datatype is "DATE".  If anyone has had a similar experience or has any ideas apart from, pulling from sql, parsing each entry individually and rearranging in python, and sending back to sql (which sounds miserable) I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in SQL:

```
sqlite> create table d (date);
sqlite> insert into d values ('12/31/2020');
sqlite> select * from d;
12/31/2020
sqlite> update d set date = substr(date,7,4) || '-' || substr(date,1,2) || '-' || substr(date,4,2);
sqlite> select * from d;
2020-12-31
sqlite>
```